# Confusion about scope property in web manifest

Tags: service-worker, manifest.json

I'm confused about what should be my `scope` property in my web manifest file.

Say, if my `start_url` is set to `https://www.example.com/`, should my `scope` be `"/"` or the same as `start_url`?

I'm using Vue3.

Note:
The main issue that I'm facing is the `service-worker` not getting detected by the browser and it figures out setting an appropriate `scope` could solve the problem it.

Answer (score 0):

The [`scope` field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/scope) in the web app manifest defines something different than a service worker registration's [`scope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/scope).

Setting `scope` in your web app manifest is not required to use a service worker or have it detected.

If you could provide some more details about how you're registering your service worker in your question, we might be able to help you further. Additionally, "[The service worker lifecycle](https://web.dev/service-worker-lifecycle/)" documentation has a lot of best practices for using service workers. I did want to share this answer to at least clarify the difference between those two `scope` values.